# Compile time selection of code to be executed in Template class

Tags: c++, c++-templates

I'm developing an IPC library based on `boost::interprocess::message_queue`.
To communicate between 2 disjoint process I've to use cross connection, i.e. `communication_module` process writes to `mq_com_send` and read from `mq_com_receive` while all other processes read from `mq_com_send` and write to `mq_com_receive`.
I wish to avoid runtime if statement and wish to generate code dependent on the template flag `communication_module`.
I'm using `constexpr` for the purpose.

```
if constexpr(communication_module == true) //For communcaition Module send data to mq_com_receive
{
    return this->mq_com_send.try_send(reinterpret_cast<void*>(&const_cast<T2&>(buffer)), sizeof(buffer), priority);
}
```

My compiler supports is limited to C++17.

I have 2 questions

1. I wish to know if this scheme is valid, are the if statements evaluated in compile time and not run-time and is this considered to be acceptable practice.
2. I also wish to know how can I validate the code being generated for the template class.

I'm using MSVC for development and testing and clang for production.

Code:

```
#pragma once
#include <boost/interprocess/ipc/message_queue.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>

//Create a full duplex message queue
//T1 -> Receive Queue
//T2 -> Transmit Queue
//communication_module -> is owner the sender or receiver
template <typename T1, typename T2, bool communication_module>
class Ipc
{
public:
    bool send(const T2& buffer, std::uint32_t priority = 0); 
    bool listen(void);
    std::optional<T1> read(void);
    bool close(void);
    //Creates a message queue with default  permissions: A null security attributes pointer for windows or 0644 for UNIX.
    Ipc(const std::string& queue_name, int message_max_number = 5) : 
        mq_com_receive(boost::interprocess::open_or_create, (queue_name + "_receive").c_str(), message_max_number, sizeof(T1)), 
            mq_com_send(boost::interprocess::open_or_create, (queue_name + "_send").c_str(), message_max_number, sizeof(T2))
                 {}
private:
    boost::interprocess::message_queue mq_com_receive;
    boost::interprocess::message_queue mq_com_send;
};

template<typename T1, typename T2, bool communication_module>
inline bool Ipc<T1, T2, communication_module>::send(const T2& buffer, std::uint32_t priority)
{
    try
    {
        if constexpr(communication_module == true) //For communcaition Module send data to mq_com_receive
        {
            return this->mq_com_send.try_send(reinterpret_cast<void*>(&const_cast<T2&>(buffer)), sizeof(buffer), priority);
        }
        else //For all other modules other than the communcaition Module send data to mq_com_receive
        {
            return this->mq_com_receive.try_send(reinterpret_cast<void*>(&const_cast<T2&>(buffer)), sizeof(buffer), priority);
        }

    }
    catch (const std::exception& ex)
    {
        //TODO Log Exception
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}

template<typename T1, typename T2, bool communication_module>
inline std::optional<T1> Ipc<T1, T2, communication_module>::read(void)
{
    try
    {
        T1 buffer;
        boost::interprocess::message_queue::size_type recieve_size;
        std::uint32_t priority;
        if constexpr(communication_module == true) //For communcaition Module read incoming data from mq_com_receive
        {
            this->mq_com_receive.try_receive(reinterpret_cast<void*>(buffer), recieve_size, priority);
            return buffer;
        }
        else //For all other modules other than the communcaition Module read incoming data from mq_com_send
        {
            this->mq_com_send.try_receive(reinterpret_cast<void*>(buffer), recieve_size, priority);
            return buffer;
        }
    }
    catch (const std::exception& ex)
    {
        //Log Error
        return std::nullopt;
    }
}
```

---

Update Read and Send method

```
template<typename T1, typename T2, bool communication_module>
inline bool Ipc<T1, T2, communication_module>::send(const T2& buffer, std::uint32_t priority)
{
    try
    {
        if constexpr(communication_module == true) //For communcaition Module send data to mq_com_receive
        {
#pragma message("send method: communication_module == true")
            return this->mq_com_send.try_send(reinterpret_cast<void*>(&const_cast<T2&>(buffer)), sizeof(buffer), priority);
        }
        else //For all other modules other than the communcaition Module send data to mq_com_receive
        {
#pragma message("send method: communication_module == false")
            return this->mq_com_receive.try_send(reinterpret_cast<void*>(&const_cast<T2&>(buffer)), sizeof(buffer), priority);
        }

    }
    catch (const std::exception& ex)
    {
        //TODO Log Exception
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}

template<typename T1, typename T2, bool communication_module>
inline std::optional<T1> Ipc<T1, T2, communication_module>::read(void)
{
    try
    {
        T1 buffer;
        boost::interprocess::message_queue::size_type recieve_size;
        std::uint32_t priority;
        if constexpr(communication_module == true) //For communcaition Module read incoming data from mq_com_receive
        {
#pragma message("read method: communication_module == true")
            this->mq_com_receive.try_receive(reinterpret_cast<void*>(buffer), recieve_size, priority);
            return buffer;
        }
        else //For all other modules other than the communcaition Module read incoming data from mq_com_send
        {
#pragma message("read method: communication_module == false")
            this->mq_com_send.try_receive(reinterpret_cast<void*>(buffer), recieve_size, priority);
            return buffer;
        }
    }
    catch (const std::exception& ex)
    {
        //Log Error
        return std::nullopt;
    }
}
```

Pragma Output

```
1>    Ipc.cpp
1>    send method: communication_module == true
1>    send method: communication_module == false
1>    read method: communication_module == true
1>    read method: communication_module == false
1>    TestApplication.cpp
1>    send method: communication_module == true
1>    send method: communication_module == false
1>    read method: communication_module == true
1>    read method: communication_module == false
1>    send method: communication_module == true
1>    send method: communication_module == false
```

Comment: Using constexpr to select code at compile time is good practice.  Validation of code should be done through unit tests. So first compile this code to a static lib, inject and dependencies it needs (through abstract baseclasses). Then link with a test framework, run your tests. And if everything is ok then link with your production code.

Comment: @PepijnKramer I was think is their any option available with MSVC or clang to generate interim source or header files whereby I can verify the code-generated for the template.

Comment: I don't know if it works with boost yet, but have a look at https://cppinsights.io/ (which can show you how templates/lambdas etc. expand).  Have you tried `Project properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessing -> Preprocess to a file: Yes (/P)` yet? (It has been so long ago that I used that I can't remember if it also expands the templates).

Comment: No, the test environment must be provided by you. This is too specific.

Comment: Another option I sometimes use is to add a `#pragma message` in the `if constexpr` branches so I know which one is instantiated (the message ends up in the compiler output)

Comment: @PepijnKramer cppinsights.io doesn't support boost. When I set `Preprocess to a file: Yes (/P)` I get an error `LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'x64\Debug\Ipc.obj'`

Comment: @PepijnKramer Looking at the #pragma message output is more confusing. No I don't know whether the if statement is evaluated at compile time or run-time.

Comment: #pragma's are evaluated at compile time.

Comment: in a template the false branch of constexpr if is discared, it must be evaluated at compile time